# Populating array of ObjectId's in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

My document contains a field called `clients` that is supposed to contain an array of client id's.

```
{
  "first_name":"Nick",
  "last_name":"Parsons",
  "email":"nick@movementstrategy.com",
  "password":"foo",
  "clients":[
    "50f5e901545cf990c500000f",
    "50f5e90b545cf990c5000010"
  ]
}
```

My data is coming in as JSON, and I directly send it to Mongo to create a document. For some reason, `clients` is not being populated when I create, so I have to manually enter them in as strings.

My schema is fairly simple, and defined as:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },  
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: String,
    clients: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
});
```

From my understanding, I've defined clients correctly. But I cannot get the clients array to populate when I am doing the create. Event the raw object that gets passed to mongo looks good.

```
{ 
    first_name: 'Zack',
    last_name: 'S',
    email: 'zack@movementstrategy.com',
    password: 'test',
    clients: [
       '50f5e901545cf990c500000f', 
       '50f5e90b545cf990c5000010' 
    ] 
}
```

Is there something special that I have to do to my input so that it's casted correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer may be outdated...

If you're going to update this collection, I would recommend using a $push update. This method of updating is designed to avoid performing updates when all you're doing is appending to an array in the collection.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: Please, show some examples in mongoose for your recommendation technique.

Comment: Examples can be found at the provided link..
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#examples

Comment: How is this related to populate array of ObjIds?

Answer (score 10):

Simple fix. Checking if the incoming array is populated. If so, I loop through each and push a converted ObjectId version into the array. Apparently `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('STRING');` is able to convert a general string to a valid mongoose id.

```
// if clients was passed with associated client ids
if (data.clients.length > 0) {

    _.map(data.clients, function(cid) {

        // push client id (converted from string to mongo object id) into clients
        user.clients.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(cid));

    });

}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Won't push duplicate the contents of user.clients?

Comment: how can i populate for example `cid's` in your map function

Comment: @PratikBothra No because he's pushing into user.clients while looping data.clients.